# Many-to-Many table is mapped as an entity with EF6 database first

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, orm, many-to-many

I have an Issue with Many-to-Many mapping. I have the following tables created on MySql database:

[image: CREATE TABLES]

In edmx I tried to map it with Update Model From Database:

[image: MAPPING TABLES]

But when the tables are mapped, the table Many-to-Many `usuarios_conquistas` is mapped as an Entity (not only a relationship between tables `usuarios` and `conquistas`):

[image: TABLES MAPPED]

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "usuario_conquistas" table should not have a column Id, it should use the columns IdUsuario and IdConquista as a composite primary key.